# How to resolve the issue of double-signin in windows after update?

Tags: windows-10

I have recently updated my windows to `Fall-Creators` update, but now I have to sign in two times for accessing the system after restarting or shutdown the system.Had anybody solved the issue?
I've visited [Microsoft site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-fall-creators-update-login-twice/3f2fa959-1d90-4a22-a92c-ff886deff4ca?auth=1) but the issue was not solved there.Had anyone any idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ok, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

This new Microsoft bug which occurs on Windows 10 Creators Update can be fixed
this way :

1. Click the **Start** button, then select **Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options**.
2. In the **Privacy** section, turn off **Use my sign in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart**.

[image]